# Pick a random Entry from a database

Tags: database, random

I am trying to code an application to help me run a quiz night.

I have different databases for different categories which I want to be able to randomly pick out a question from, and show it on screen.

So far I have got:

```
 If LCat.Text = "Film" Then
        LQues.Text = Film_QuestionTextBox.Text
        Film_UsedTextBox.Text = "Y"
        FilmBindingSource.EndEdit()
        FilmTableAdapter.Update(Me.Database1DataSet)
    End If
```

This picks the first question from the corresponding database, but how to make it a random question.

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL at least, you can use this SQL to get a single random row from the `Questions` table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM [Questions] ORDER BY NEWID()
```

The `NEWID()` function generates a random `UNIQUEIDENTIFIER` for every row.

Comment: @CraigEmerson What service? Does it have a query language?

Comment: just the one built into visual basic 2010 express